# What's the difference between "=" & "=>" and "@variable", "@@variable" and ":variable" in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know these are the basics of rails but i still don't know the full difference between `=` sign and `=>` and the difference between `@some_variable`, `@@some_variable` and `:some_variable` in rails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK.

The difference between the `=` and the `=>` operators is that the first is assignment, the second represents an association in a hash (associative array). So `{ :key => 'val' }` is saying "create an associative array, with `:key` being the key, and `'val'` being the value". If you want to sound like a Rubyist, we call this the "hashrocket". (Believe it or not, this isn't the most strange operator in Ruby; we also have the `<=>`, or "spaceship operator".)

You may be confused because there is a bit of a shortcut you can use in methods, if the last parameter is a hash, you can omit the squiggly brackets (`{}`). so calling `render :partial => 'foo'` is basically calling the render method, passing in a hash with a single key/value pair. Because of this, you often see a hash as the last parameter to sort of have a poor man's optional parameters (you see something similar done in JavaScript too).

In Ruby, any normal word is a local variable. So `foo` inside a method is a variable scoped to the method level. Prefixing a variable with `@` means scope the variable to the instance. So `@foo` in a method is an instance level.

`@@` means a class variable, meaning that `@@` variables are in scope of the class, and all instances.

`:` means symbol. A symbol in Ruby is a special kind of string that implies that it will be used as a key. If you are coming from C#/Java, they are similar in use to the key part of an enum. There are some other differences too, but basically any time you are going to treat a string as any sort of key, you use a symbol instead.

Answer (score 15):

Wow, a that's a lot of different concepts together.

1) `=` is plain old assignment.

```
a = 4;
puts a
```

2) `=>` is used to declare hashes

```
hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3}
puts hash['b'] # prints 2
```

3) `@var` lets you access object instance variable.

```
class MyObject
    def set_x(x)
        @x = x
    end
    def get_x
        @x
    end
end

o = MyObject.new
o.set_x 3
puts o.get_x # prints 3
```

4) `@@var` lets you access class ('static') variables.

```
class MyObject
    def set_x(x)
        @@x = x # now you can access '@@x' from other MyObject instance
    end
    def get_x
        @@x
    end
end

o1 = MyObject.new
o1.set_x 3
o2 = MyObject.new
puts o2.get_x  # prints 3, even though 'set_x' was invoked on different object
```

5)  I usually think of `:var` as special 'label' class. Example 2 can be rephrased like this

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
puts hash[:b] # prints 2
```

Comment: example 3 and 4 are confusing for me, I cannot see difference in example 3 and 4.

Comment: @Simon Run the example #4 with @x instead of @@x and you'll see the difference