# Rails 4 - saving object with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a parent model that has one child model with nested attributes. I have a single form that updates both parent and child.

Here are my models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Form view:

```
<%= form_for @parent, do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :parent_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for @parent.child do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :child_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Parent controller:

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController      
  def update
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])    
    @parent.update(params.require(:parent).permit(:parent_name, child_attributes: [:child_name]))

    redirect_to @parent
  end
end
```

When I save the form, the parent updates but the child doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a problem in the nested part of your form code, it should be

```
<%= form_for @parent, do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :parent_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :child do |c| %>  <<<<<<<<<<< this line was wrong
    <%= c.text_field :child_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

You have to pass the id in the params attributes too :

```
@parent.update(params.require(:parent).permit(:parent_name, child_attributes: [:id, :child_name]))
```

Cheers

Comment: That works, thanks! Why do I have to use the symbol and not the object?

Comment: A bit long to explain, but look here http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables , and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211724/ruby-difference-between-variable-and-variable.

Answer (score 1):

**In your controller**

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController      
  def edit
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
    @child = @parent.child.build
  end
end
```

**In your view**

```
<%= form_for @parent, do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for @child do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming `parent_name` and `child_name` was here to illustrate your need. Your attributes should not be name-spaced like this.

You also have to pass the `id` in the `permit` method like this

```
child_attributes: [:id, :name]
```

Or using `child_name`

```
child_attributes: [:id, :child_name]
```

This is not well documented at this time.